# right format for sscanf function in C

Tags: c

I have a string `"h264:640x480:4:30000"`. I used sscanf function as follow.

```
char res[16] = { 0 };
int quality = 0;
int fps = 0;
sscanf(temp1, "h264:%s:%d:%d", res, &quality, &fps);
```

when this function is executed. I was expecting "640x480" in "res", "4" in "quality" and "3000" in "fps". but it copied whole string in "res" and other two variable values remained 0.

what is the correct format for this problem.

Comment: OT: 30000 fps? Really? Also 3000 is much, isn't it?

Comment: @alk IP camera provides this string. fps is calculated by dividing this value by 1000. I wrote string as it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following `sscanf()` string format

```
sscanf(temp1, "h264:%[^:]:%d:%d", res, &quality, &fps);
```

`%s` will catch all charachters in the string till it find a white space or reach the end of the string. so `%s` is not a good choice.

`%[^:]` will catch all charachters in the string till it find the `':'` charachter or reach the end of the string

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to explicitly set accepted characters within `[]`? Something like `[0-9x]`.

Comment: @SarfrazAhmed Answer updated forthe explaination of why using this format

Answer (score 1):

[sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

`int sscanf( const char          *buffer, const char          *format, ... );`

`int sscanf( const char *restrict buffer, const char *restrict format, ... );`

reads the data from `null-terminated` character string buffer

When you did `%s`,  it intakes a string which is null terminated. Hence it copied the whole
string (with `:`) and passed nothing to the other two.

As stated by Mohamed already `sscanf(temp1, "h264:%[^:]:%d:%d", res, &quality, &fps);`   helps because it matches a **non-empty** ***sequence*** of character from set of characters.
If the first character of the set is ^, then all characters **not in** the set i.e with `[ ]` are matched.